# Making textboxes readonly using style

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I've a C#/WPF application.On my Mainwindow.xaml,I'm programmatically loading other views.
There's a checbox on MainWindow.xaml.When its clicked, I need to make all textbox controls on the screen as readonly.
The code is working for controls on Mainwindow but not for textboxes on AView.xaml

What am I missing here please?Or is there any other way of achieving this functionality?

Thanks.

Here's my code:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsCheckboxChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}" >
                <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:VModelA}"  >
                        <Views:AView/>
                    </DataTemplate>                    
            </ContentPresenter>
```

MainWindowResources.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="ReadOnlyStyle">
        <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="{Binding Path=IsCheckboxChecked}"/>        
    </Style>

<Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="ReadOnlyStyleChild">
        <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="{Binding Path=IsCheckboxCheckedChild}"/>
    </Style>
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
private static MainWindowViewModel _instance = new MainWindowViewModel();

public static MainWindowViewModel Instance
        {
            get {
                return _instance;
            }
        }

 public bool IsCheckboxChecked
        {
            get { 

                return m_isCheckboxChecked;
            }
            set
            {               
                m_isCheckboxChecked = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsCheckboxChecked");                
            }        
        }
```

VModelA.cs:

```
public bool IsCheckboxCheckedChild
            {
                get {
                    return MainWindowViewModel.Instance.IsCheckboxChecked;
                }

            }
```

AView.xaml

```
 <TextBox Style="{DynamicResource ReadOnlyStyleChild}">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the output window when debugging your app, I suspect you'll see messages about binding failures for this:

```
{Binding Path=IsCheckboxChecked}
```

Binding in styles is tricky to do. What is the source? You might need to specify `ElementName` or `RelativeSource`.

Comment: Thanks Drew.I did try below but now none of the textboxes(MainWindow and AView) are getting set as readonly.<Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsCheckboxChecked}"/>

Comment: Self will be the checkbox. Don't you have that property somewhere else?